# putting two curves in a graph in cOutVector

Tags: omnet++

I have these two parameters, (parameter 1 and parameter 2) that I want to compare them through time and examine the effect of them on each other. I am using objects of class cOutVector (using record() method)

I want to put the values of these two parameters in one graph as Y axis and time as X axis.

The second type of graph is comprised of parameter 1 on X axis and parameter 2 on Y axis. Is it possible to do this type of graph?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have You tried to use R?  It is the perfect thing for statistical computing and plotting Your data.

Try it - You'll solve Your problem with this. OMNeT provides a extra packet for the R environment, which helps You to analyse the cOutVector structure.

[A tutorial can be found here](https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp-resultfiles/wiki/Tutorial-for-the-omnetpp-r-package)